# Cannot restore MariaDB dump after upgrade from 10.6.10 to 10.6.15

Tags: mariadb, computed-column, mariadb-10.6

I have just updated MariaDB server from 10.6.10 to 10.6.15 on my development machine, and trying to restore a previously working SQL dump now fails.

Here is an example of failing query:

```
CREATE TABLE `lin_98_41_strumenti_categorie` (
  `id_categoria` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_azienda` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `id_sede` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `revisione_documento` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `id_macchina` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_attrezzo` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_impianto` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_opera_provvisionale` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_strumento` char(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat_ws('',if(`id_macchina` is not null,'M',NULL),if(`id_attrezzo` is not null,'A',NULL),if(`id_impianto` is not null,'I',NULL),if(`id_opera_provvisionale` is not null,'O',NULL))) VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_categoria`,`id_azienda`,`id_sede`,`revisione_documento`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_id_macchina_lin_98_41_strumenti_categorie` (`id_macchina`,`id_azienda`,`id_sede`,`revisione_documento`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_id_attrezzo_lin_98_41_strumenti_categorie` (`id_attrezzo`,`id_azienda`,`id_sede`,`revisione_documento`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_id_impianto_lin_98_41_strumenti_categorie` (`id_impianto`,`id_azienda`,`id_sede`,`revisione_documento`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_id_opera_provvisionale_lin_98_41_strumenti_categorie` (`id_opera_provvisionale`,`id_azienda`,`id_sede`,`revisione_documento`),
  KEY `fk_main_lin_98_41_strumenti_categorie` (`id_azienda`,`id_sede`,`revisione_documento`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_attrezzo_lin_98_41_strumenti_categorie` FOREIGN KEY (`id_attrezzo`) REFERENCES `agews_attrezzi` (`id_attrezzo`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_impianto_lin_98_41_strumenti_categorie` FOREIGN KEY (`id_impianto`) REFERENCES `agews_impianti` (`id_impianto`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_macchina_lin_98_41_strumenti_categorie` FOREIGN KEY (`id_macchina`) REFERENCES `agews_macchine` (`id_macchina`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_opera_provvisionale_lin_98_41_strumenti_categorie` FOREIGN KEY (`id_opera_provvisionale`) REFERENCES `agews_opere_provvisionali` (`id_opera_provvisionale`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_main_lin_98_41_strumenti_categorie` FOREIGN KEY (`id_azienda`, `id_sede`, `revisione_documento`) REFERENCES `lin_98_41` (`id_azienda`, `id_sede`, `revisione_documento`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;
```

The error is in the last `GENERATED ALWAYS` field marked as `STORED`, if I manually change the type to `VIRTUAL` it works.

The error just says:

> ERROR 1901 (HY000) at line 420329: Function or expression 'id_macchina' cannot be used in the GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause of `tipo_strumento`

but it gives no useful indications as to **why** now it cannot be used.

However, this SQL dump worked without modifications with version 10.6.10, is it possible there was such a backward-incompatbile change in the latest 10.6 version? I have looked the release notes, but I didn't found anything which should justify suche breaking change.

Comment: 5 unique keys is probably a mistake.  Can you justify having more than 2?

Comment: What is the setting of `SQL_MODE`?

Comment: The unique keys are correct as they are, and SQL_MODE is `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`, anyway I have already found the 'cause of the problem, which was confirmed on MariaDB's bug tracker by the devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found out what happened by creating [a ticket](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32030) on MariaDb's bug tracker, it seems this is intentional:

> If it's due to foreign keys then yes, indeed, it is intentional. The way MariaDB works, and always did, foreign key cascading actions are applied to child tables on a very low level where the server cannot update STORED generated column values anymore. In other words, if a STORED generated column depends on a column that can be modified via a cascade action, this STORED column can become out of sync with other columns. Basically, it'll have an incorrect value. That's why such a table structure is no longer allowed.

> We're planning to lift this restriction. [MDEV-31942](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31942) (or [MDEV-22361](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22361)) when implemented, will allow us to recalculate STORED generated columns on UPDATE CASCADE and SET NULL actions.